# Keys from my keyboard do no respond

Tags: keyboard

A few days ago, I updated an Intel Bluetooth driver hoping it would solve a connection problem-it did not. My laptop keyboard now has a few keys which do not work anymore. I wonder, based on the pattern, whether it is linked to the update or if it would have been damaged, potentially because of dust/humidity.

Here is the detail:

- MSI GL62 6QF (https://www.msi.com/Laptop/GL62-6QF)
- French keyboard (had to switch to a UK keymapping for the test)
- I have now opened the laptop and removed dust on the side of the motherboard- I do not know how to access the side of the keyboard.
- I have deleted and reinstalled most drivers since.
- I have a dual-boot computer and the problem is on both W10 and Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Keyboard test:
[image]

French keyboard layout:
[image]

Should I visit a tech center?

Comment: I don't know how a Bluetooth driver change would have any impact on the internal keyboard for your laptop. To determine whether this is a hardware or software issue, connect a USB keyboard to your laptop and test it to see whether it has the same/similar issues. If it does not, the problem is physically with your laptop keyboard and you should replace it. If it DOES have the same problems, you have a system/software problem.

Comment: 1. As suggested, test a USB keyboard. 2. If there are issues with a few keys, look for a swollen battery.